# CMake project with vcpkg links to qt always in debug with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cmake, vcpkg

I've the following cmake project:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10.0)

project (proj)

set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set (CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package (Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package (Qt5Gui REQUIRED)

include_directories (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set (PROJECT_SRC
  main.cpp
  )

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRC})
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui)

add_custom_command (TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Widgets> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
add_custom_command (TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Gui> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
add_custom_command (TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Core> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```

I use Visual Studio 2019, and I've the following CMake settings:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "msvc_x64_x64"
      ],
      "buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/build-debug",
      "installRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/install-debug",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE",
          "value": "D:/Projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        },
        {
          "name": "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET",
          "value": "x64-windows"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-Release",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Release",
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "msvc_x64_x64"
      ],
      "buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/build-release",
      "installRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/install-release",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE",
          "value": "D:/Projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        },
        {
          "name": "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET",
          "value": "x64-windows"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I'm using Qt installed with `vcpkg`.

If I build in debug in Visual Studio everything it's ok, while if I build in release, by choosing `x64-Release` in Visual Studio configuration it build, but then project fails to start because it looks for Qt5 debug libraries instead of release ones, even if Qt release libraries are copied into the build folder of the application.

What should I do in order to create the CMake project and build in release property in Visual Studio?